# Unwanted bottom margin/padding in div

Tags: html, css

I have created a div with 4 boxes inside. Each one contains an image with an overlay on hover, but for some reason I have ended up with a margin/padding at the bottom of each box and I cant figure out why.

I have even tried using float intead of inline-block for .showcase-item, but nothing I do will remove it. Can anyone help?

HTML:

```
<div class="showcase">
<div class="showcase-item"><ul class="img-list"><li>
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000442759461/b483cdd049f470928e7b20051f95b8cc.jpeg" style="width: 100%"><span class="text-content"><span>Place Name</span></span></li></ul>
</div><div class="showcase-item"><ul class="img-list"><li>
  <img src="http://www.proprofs.com/quiz-school/upload/yuiupload/1756353485.jpg" style="width: 100%"><span class="text-content"><span>Place Name</span></span></li></ul>
</div><div class="showcase-item">
<img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000442759461/b483cdd049f470928e7b20051f95b8cc.jpeg" style="width: 100%">
</div><div class="showcase-item">
<img src="http://www.proprofs.com/quiz-school/upload/yuiupload/1756353485.jpg" style="width: 100%">
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.showcase-item {
width: 25%;
background: black;
display: inline-block;
margin: 0;
position:relative;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
ul.img-list {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
 text-align: center;
}
ul.img-list li {
margin: 0;
}
span.text-content {
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
color: white;
cursor: pointer;
display: table;
height: 100%;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0; margin: 0;  width: 100%;
}
span.text-content span {
display: table-cell;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
}
pan.text-content {
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
color: white;
cursor: pointer;
display: table;
height: 100%;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
opacity: 0;
}
ul.img-list li:hover span.text-content {
opacity: 1;
}
span.text-content {
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
color: white;
cursor: pointer;
display: table;
height: 100%;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
-moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
-o-transition: opacity 500ms;
transition: opacity 500ms;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ambersabre/9r7wvnsx/4/

Comment: Why do you use `ul` elements?

Comment: I was following a tutorial on how to create a hover effect which suggested using a list to achieve this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's some sort of bug with images. Apply `img {display: block;}`

Answer (score 3):

`Inline-block` elements behave just like letters: they create a little gap after each 'letter'. So I recommend you to change `margin: 0` to:

```
.showcase-item {
    margin-left: -5px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9r7wvnsx/5/

Also you can read about this problem here: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Interesting Read, Thank you  :)

Answer (score 2):

`<img>` is an inline element by default. This removes the gap:

```
img{
vertical-align: top;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/9r7wvnsx/6/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
  .showcase-item {
        width: 25%;
        background: black;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0;
        position:relative;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }
    ul.img-list {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      text-align: center;
    }

    ul.img-list li {
      margin: 0;
    }
    span.text-content {
      background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
      color: white;
      cursor: pointer;
      display: table;
      height: 100%;
      left: 0;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0; margin: 0;  width: 100%;
    }

    span.text-content span {
      display: table-cell;
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }

    span.text-content {
      background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
      color: white;
      cursor: pointer;
      display: table;
      height: 100%;
      left: 0;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      opacity: 0;
    }

    ul.img-list li:hover span.text-content {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    span.text-content {
      background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
      color: white;
      cursor: pointer;
      display: table;
      height: 100%;
      left: 0;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
      -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
      -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
      transition: opacity 500ms;
    }

    img {
        display:block;
    }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9r7wvnsx/7/)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to remove padding/margin from the div:

```
<div style="margin-bottom:0; padding-bottom:0"></div>
```